# Access How to make one cell value depend on the value in another

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, join

Note: Whole question has been rewritten for clarity.

I've been tearing my hair out regarding this seemingly simple problem where i know exactly what i want to do, but not how to do it.

I have 2 tables with the following relevant columns

```
Products: ProductID, ProductName
```

Each entry is one product made by the company. ProductID is primary key. New entries are made very rarely.

```
Orders: OrderID, ProductName, ArticleID
```

Each entry is an order made to the company. OrderID is primary key. New entries are made continuously.

Here's the user experience I'm looking for:

User enters name of the product into Orders.ProductName.

Orders.ProductID automatically becomes the ProductID of the product.
This is figured out by going to the table Products, to the row where the ProductName matches the name entered by the user, and returning the ProductID on that row.

In Excel, this would be like entering "=" into a cell followed by the required code. I don't want to store any data in the automatically generated field since it exists elsewhere and it's good database practice to not store the same information in two different places.

I've tried several SQL queries, including inner joins, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to grab info from a single cell (not predefined in the code. the row to take ProductID from depends on the user-written Product Name).

again: Preferably all of this would be done in a way that doesn't just enter the end data INTO the cell, but rather have it all as a function that is reevaluated at all times should any data change (just like "=SUM(B4, B5)" in excel)

Comment: you mean you want records that fit that row unique ID? if thats the case why not just WHERE id = what id you want?

Comment: Why `mysql` tag when you're using MS Access?

Comment: @StevenSmith: The problem is, i want the query to work on all rows, not on a specific row entered in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok not sure what your asking but here goes.

your query seems ok other than you need it to be selective based on a reason.

What i mean is you currently return all records that match both tables, you a want to filter this based on a drop down box?

if this is a true you can do this using a MS SQL stored procedure.
like the following:

```
USE [YourDatabaseName]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProcedureName]
@dropDownID int
AS

SELECT Articles.ArticleID
FROM Articles 
INNER JOIN Orders ON Articles.ArticleNr=Orders.ArticleNr
WHERE articles.ID = @dropDownID
```

then in your code vb or c# simply pass the value of the selected dropdown to the procedure and return the results.

Is this what your after?

Comment: The Orders.ArticleNr drop down box is in place, in which i can choose any value that appears in Articles.ArticleNr. I don't care about the getting the info from the dropdown box specifically, I just want to be able to figure out which ArticleID the written/selected ArticleNr implies.
I tried out your query, but MS Access doesn't recognize "USE" and thus doesn't let me run the query.

Comment: Ah my mistake, forgot your relize your using Access.

Answer (score 0):

You might be designing like this

articleTable -- ArticleID, ArticleNr

Orders -- OrderID, ArticleID

```
select Orders.OrderID, Orders.ArticleID, articleTable.ArticleNr
from Orders
    left join articleTable on Orders.ArticleID = articleTable.ArticleID
```

> When a new order is entered into the Order table, and the user types
>   in "96964-A" into the ArticleNr, i want ArticleID to automatically
>   become "2". It would be optimal if this worked the other way around as
>   well.

just make the ArticleID as identity in SQL Server or Autonumber in MS Access

Comment: Articles.ArticleID is an Autonumber. (and the primary key for that table)

It is the **Orders**.ArticleID that I want to automate.
When Orders.ArticleNr is entered into the database, i want the value of Orders.ArticleID on the same row to become the Articles.ArticleID from the row where the ArticleNr values match.
Also, I ran your query but it seems to be the other way around than what I am looking for. What i want the query to return is one instance of Articles.ArticleID